# Information for xyz project

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, there is an option called 'Information for xyz project' under 'Project' menu. It shows the total number of lines compiled and other info. Unfortunately, the manual is null for this feature. It only says something like this: "Views the program compilation information and compilation status for your project".

For example, for one of my projects it shows about 200000 lines. What is this number? Does it include the code in 3rd party VCLs and Borland code/libraries? If yes, is it only the code necessary to run the application?

Comment: Meaning is exactly the same as `dcc` summary output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need Project information like total source code size effective lines and so on you can download and install cnPack IDE wizards. It's free and Open source

visit http://www.cnpack.org

Answer (score 3):

The number of lines is just the number of Pascal lines that were compiled. It does not include any lines of codes that were compiled as libraries. They are just linked in at link time as precompiled DCU's.

Comment: Actually, number of source lines processed at last compilation (ofc, including rebuilt dependencies, if any).

Comment: @user759588: Very true, forgot those bits.

Comment: Thanks Steve and user759588. So, that information doesn't really tell something useful...